# Datatypes of Knex that I can use with PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

To clarify my question, at the moment I am creating a Migration file for a table that will be in my database. But I cannot find all the datatypes I can use, I wonder where could I find them since PostgreSQL provides a lot of datatypes. And, I wonder if I am able to use some of them.

My migration file:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('organizations', function (table) {
    table.increments('id').unsigned().primary()

    table.dateTime('registeredAt').notNull()
  })
}
```

As seen above, I am able to use `datetime` but could I use, for example, `cdr` which is for IP addresses in v4 or v6. And also, if exists, a documentation of what maps to what would be very useful.

Also, if you are able to, a definite answer with an array of IP addresses column would be very kind of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knex has a [specificType](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-specificType) method that accepts any valid DB column type.

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('organizations', function (table) {
    table.specificType('columnName', 'tinyInt');
  })
}
```